# passing 3D arrays usnig MPI_ALLGATHERV

Tags: arrays, 3d, mpi, fortran77

I'm trying to pass 3D arrays to all other processes using MPI_ALLGATHERV. v1 is a common block array.

```
parameter (nprocz=48,nzro=1)
do 1 i=i101,i102
  do 2 j = je0, je1-1
  do 2  k = ke0, ke1
    v1(k,j,i) = v1(k,j,i)*0.015*float(i-iv0)
2    continue
1   continue      
nmpi01=floor((iv0-ie0-nzro)/(nprocz-1))
if (mpirank .le. nprocz-2) then
   i101=ie0+(mpirank*nmpi01)
   i102=ie0+(mpirank+1)*nmpi01-1
else
   i101=ie0+(mpirank*nmpi01)
   i102=iv0-1
endif
scount=(i102-i101+1)*(je1-je0)*(ke1-ke0+1)
rcount(mpirank+1)=scount
displs(mpirank+1)=mpirank*scount+1 call
MPI_ALLGATHERV(v1(1,1,i101),scount,MPI_REAL,v1(1,1,1)  ,rcount,displs,MPI_REAL,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr004)
```

but i got this error as many as my processes:

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Allgatherv: Internal MPI error!, error stack:
...
MPIR_Localcopy(378).......: memcpy arguments alias each other, dst=0x7ccddb44  
src=0x7ccddb40 len=3642752
```

then i tried, MPI_IN_PLACE like this:

```
 MPI_ALLGATHERV(MPI_IN_PlACE,scount,MPI_REAL,v1(1,1,1),   
 rcount,displs,MPI_REAL,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr004)
```

but memory has been using incrementally until the probram crashed.

Answer (score 0):

`MPI_ALLGATHERV` requires that each ranks specifies the sizes and displacements for every rank in the communicator. What you do you only fill the values for a single rank:

```
rcount(mpirank+1)=scount
displs(mpirank+1)=mpirank*scount+1
```

Instead you should loop over the ranks and compute all elements of `rcount` and `displs` in each rank:

```
integer :: myscount, myi101

displs(1) = 0
do rank = 0, nprocz-1
   nmpi01=floor((iv0-ie0-nzro)/(nprocz-1))
   if (rank .le. nprocz-2) then
      i101=ie0+(rank*nmpi01)
      i102=ie0+(rank+1)*nmpi01-1
   else
      i101=ie0+(rank*nmpi01)
      i102=iv0-1
   endif
   scount=(i102-i101+1)*(je1-je0)*(ke1-ke0+1)
   rcount(rank+1)=scount
   if (rank .gt. 0) then
      displs(rank+1) = displs(rank) + rcount(rank)
   endif
   if (rank .eq. mpirank) then
      myscount = scount
      myi101 = i101
   end if
end do

scount = myscount
i101 = myi101

call mpi_allgatherv(...)
```

Note also that the way `displs` is computed is probably wrong. If the data received is to be placed with no gaps in between, the following relation should hold: `displs(i) = sum(rcount(1:i-1))`. **Edit:** I've changed the code above with one that properly computes the elements of the `displs` array.

Comment: thanks, it works but still wrong results. 1-in my case, results at each part are used for the next part, especially after `mpi_allgatherv`.so do i need to add `mpi_barrier` after each `mpi_allgatherv`? 2-should `mpi_in_place` be used? consider i have only one 3d array `v1` that each sub-array `v1(1,1,i)` is calculated by some process and i want to put the calculated subarray in the appropriate part of the same array. 3- i guess `displs(i) = sum(rcount(1:i-1))` is not correct. actually it should be `displs(i) = sum(rcount(1:i-1))+1 for i=>2` considering that always `displs(1)=1` in fortran77

Comment: so, i corrected to this: before the loop `displs(1)=1`, inside the loop `displs(rank+2)=rank*scount+1` and after the loop `displs(nprocz+1)=0`. am i right?

Comment: Displacements are in number of elements after the beginning of the array, therefore `displs(1)` should be 0. Also `scount` depends on the rank and you cannot simply multiply it by the rank in the loop.

Comment: 1-i corrected to `displs(1)=0` and changed `displs(rank+1)=rank*scount+1` to `displs(rank+2)=(rank+1)*scount`. still wrong results although better than before.  2-i dont get your second sentence. `scount` of course depends on the rank, thats why i calculated the indices `i101` and `i102` based on the rank and then found `scount`  based on them.  3- besides i dont need to have `scount` out of the loop, because when using `mpi_in_place`parameters `scount` and `send type` will be ignored.  still im confused whats the problem.

Comment: still the problem insists even after adding `mpi_barrier` before each `mpi_allgather`.

Comment: My point is, since `scount` is a function of the rank, i.e. it is different for each rank, then `rank*scount` cannot replace a sum of all `rcount()` elements with smaller ranks. Also, though `MPI_ALLGATHER(V)` is often not globally synchronous (since it allows for process early exit), you still should not need an additional barrier.

Comment: See the updated answer for a suggestion on how to compute the elements of `displs`.

Comment: i got the point! because the size of `rcount` elements  differ for each `rank` in `mpi_allgatherv`, we should add up the `rcount` elements to get the appropriate `displs` elements values. while in `mpi_allgather` we can easily multiply the `rank` by `rcount` elements to get the `displs` because all `rcount` elements have the same size. thats the difference between `mpi_allgather` and `mpi_allgatherv`.